# Send URL folder to URL field in listitem

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow

I have a SharePointlist (AddressList) with 2 columns: Address and URL.
And there is a Flow.

Whenever an item is created, a new folder (AddressFolder) is created with the name of the Address value from the AddressList. So far, so good.

However, now, i would like to update the URL field in the AddressList with the URL of the newly made Folder. Because i would like to be able to click directly from the list to the corresponding folder.
How can i achieve this?

Comment: Where are you creating the new folder? In same list or in another list/library?

Answer (score 0):

According to my research, this requirement cannot be fulfilled.

Since this folder is automatically created by a flow, we cannot get the URL of the folder directly in the current flow. In theory, we should create a second flow. The trigger condition is to trigger the flow when a new folder is created in the list.

But there is no trigger condition for folder in flow：

[image]

Comment: I see your point with the second flow. 

But would it would work with the trigger When a file is created or modified in a folder? Because, as it happens, in my flow a file is also created after the folder is created. 
So, that could could be a trigger. But then I would then like to fetch the url of the folder and send it to a column in a SP list.

Comment: My research shows that [Create new folder] action returns [Link to Item] property containing the url of the newly created folder which can be used to update URL of the originating item (ID from the [When a new item is  created]) using [Update item] action. Or am I missing something on the requirement?